# Reutilizar una variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

miren la variable x la quiero reutilizar en el siguiente metodo y no puedo,
tengo que hacerlo en un solo metodo?

```
class fabrica:
    def __init(self):
        self.compra = compra
        print("perfume 12$-labial 15$-zapato 20$")


    #algoritmo de compras   
    def compras(self):
            self.registros = []
            self.cantidad = int(input("cuantas compras haras :"))

            #se repite el num de veces == cantidad
            self.suma = ""
            i = 0
            j = 0
            while i < self.cantidad:
                self.compra = int(input("precio del producto :")) 
                j=j+self.compra
                i+=1

                if i == self.cantidad:
                    self.registros.append(j)

                    for x in self.registros:
                        print(f"cancele ${x}")

        def cobrar(self):
            self.cancelar = int(input("cancele el producto :")) 

            while self.cancelar < x:
                self.cancelar = int(input("cancele el producto :"))

                if self.cancelar > x:
                    self.cancelar = self.cancelar-x
                    print(f"su cambio {self.cancelar}")


    ob1 = fabrica()
    ob1.compras()
    ob1.cobrar()
```

Comment: quien hizo eso muchas gracias porque yo no pude

Comment: `x` ni siquiera es una variable, es anónima solo sirve para el ciclo, además su valor cambia no está definida para nada.

Answer (score 3):

En el método cobrar la variable `x` no está definida. Si tu intención fue utilizar la variable `x` de compras no lo vas a poder hacer porque en el método `compras` la variable `x` tiene alcance para ese método. Fuera de él no existe. Si quieres que `x` sea visible para todos los métodos la tienes que hacer variable de objeto: `self.x` e inicializarla en el `__init__` (aunque es opcional, es recomendable).

Otra forma de hacerlo es que la variable `x` la definas como global antes de la definición de la clase y en la clase haciendo referencia a ésta.

Comment: muchas gracias me fue de utilidad

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres utilizar la variable "x" en cualquier parte sin problemas, tienes 2 opciones:

**1.-** Podrías declararla como global y en cada método tendrías especificarla con la palabra reservada "global" si quieres modificar su valor.

**2.-** La segunda es como te comentaron antes, en tu método **init** declaras esa variable, ya sea de forma en la que inicializas su valor o la declaras en el mismo init con 0. Ejemplo:

```
def __init(self):
    self.x = 0
```

Y ya cada que quieras usar esa variable, que ahora es parte de esas clase la tendrías que llamar así: `self.x`

Comment: muchas gracias por tu tiempo